# SDL_FillRect Not Drawing?

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, render, particle-system

I'm making a game in C++ with SDL, and I want to render particles with SDL_FillRect().
I've played with the code for hours, but no matter what I do, the particles are not drawing.
This is the code in my Render function (I made sure that I was in fact calling the function):

```
void Particle::Render()
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    //rect.w = Particle::Particle_Size;
    //rect.h = Particle::Particle_Size;
    rect.w = 8;
    rect.h = 8;
    surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,8,8,32,0,0,0,0);
    if(SDL_FillRect(surface,&rect,SDL_MapRGB(surface->format,0,0,0)) != 0) printf("Error");
    //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,texture,NULL,&rect);
}
```

The console isn't printing "Error", so the SDL_FillRect() is successful. However, no rects are being drawn to the screen.
I tried creating a texture with SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() with that surface passed in, and then used SDL_RenderCopy, which is commented out in the above function, but it worked before I commented it out. I want to use SDL_FillRect so I could have colored textures though.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use this function to do what you are looking for:

```
   SDL_RenderFillRect()
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect

You would have to set the renderer color before with:

```
   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor();
```

I think you could also update the window surface to get what you have to work. 
That would use

```
   SDL_UpdateWindowSurface().
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateWindowSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! The UpdateWindowSurface() is definitely getting me somewhere, I can actually see something! The coloring is extremely strange though, so I'm not sure if I'll use this method, but the RenderFillRect() certainly looks promising. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` function creates an off-screen surface.  If you want to draw to the screen, you will have to draw to the surface returned by `SDL_GetWindowSurface()`.

That is, if you are using SDL 2.0.